# Principles of application design

Tags: design-patterns

I've been a programmer for a few years now but want to try and become a better programmer by doing some proper application design instead of just jumping in to coding straight away. I've got a new application to create and want to start with this.

I don't want to go into full design right now but what could I do to show an understanding of the application in roughly 30 mins?

I was thinking of doing a use case to show how I understand how people would use it and then doing a class diagram. What other models can I use?

I've had a look at related questions but most of them go into quite a lot of detail and as I said this needs to take about 30 minutes!

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 30 minutes plan:

1. Write down all roles (plus very short description) that interact with your application (admin, user, player, developer, ...). 10 minutes.
2. Write down the main features (use cases). You can model this later. 5 minutes.
3. Write down the known techniqual requirements/boundaries (programming lang, infrastructure, data bases, etc). 5 minutes.

Finally:

1. Find a sentence that describes your application precisely. 5 minutes.
2. Take a mirror and explain yourself the software you are building right next. 5 minutes.

Comment: that's absolutely correct, but this isn't *design* (the 'how'). it's *analysis* (the 'what'). design would come afterwards, and would include module/ class / sequence diagrams. I beleive this is an important destinction. both are necessary.

Comment: i was laying out widely the term "show an understanding of the application in roughly 30 mins".

Comment: yep, I agree with you. I was just pointing that out to ADringer and anyone else who might be cofusing design with analysis.

Comment: @sJHonny What's your answer to this question?

Comment: basically same as yours (actually probably not as good) + the remark that design is needed in addition to analysis.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I'm looking for! If you were to have another half an hour, what would the design stages be? Would this be the class diagram?

Answer (score 1):

Well, regarding sJhonnys comment to more focus on the design part. However, design must follow architecture. The next 30 minutes:

1. Identify the tiers (data, business logic, ui) your application will have - 5 min.
2. Identify the major components (own components to be created, 3rd party, ext. services) your application needs to use - 10 min.
3. Create a basic component diagram showing the interfaces (reads, notifies, stores, manages, ...) between these tiers and components. - 10  min.
4. Jump in the role of an architecture and explain your technical lead what your team is going to create and focus on:

   - benefits
   - new concepts and topics your team will encounter
   - risks that may delay the project - sportive 5 min.